# Type Conversion Error in Copy activity: Azure data factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to load multiple csv files from blob to Azure MySQL. I am using getMetadata activity and foreach activity, within forEach activity one copy activity to copy data from blob to sink. Pipeline is failing with error

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "'Type=Microsoft.Azure.Data.Governance.Plugins.Core.TypeConversionException,Message=Exception occurred when converting value '' for column name 'DATASTORE_ID' from type 'String' (precision:, scale:) to type 'Int32' (precision:0, scale:0). Additional info: Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary,''Type=System.FormatException,Message=Input string was not in a correct format.,Source=mscorlib,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy data1",
    "details": []
}
```

I am not importing any schema in Mapping tab.
please suggest the solution.

Thanks in Advance.

Geetha.

Comment: According the error message, your csv columns have the empty/null value in the column which cause the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'Copy Data' with 'Data Flow' with straight field to field mapping and the copy from blob to sink works fine.